# How to query a item inside of an object in a array In Mongodb

Tags: python, arrays, mongodb, pymongo, cart

Hello not sure how to properly ask this question but my problem is I am learning to build  a shopping cart with mongoddb as the db. When a user adds a product to their cart I want to see if they already have the item in the cart. How can I query the db to see if a product_id does or does not already  exists in the db. This is my cart db schema and I am also using python and pymongo if I could get an example code thanks.

```
{
  "_id": "5ec2df02e10dce76aa83b8b7",
  "cart_session": "test",
  "customer_id": 101,
  "cart_total": 20,
  "cart_items": 3,
  "products": [
    {
      "product_id": 1,
      "product_name": "Yellow T-Shirt",
      "price": 10,
      "quantity": 3,
      "image": "imageurl"
    },
    {
      "product_id": 2,
      "product_name": "Red Braclet",
      "price": 5,
      "quantity": 1,
      "image": "imageurl"
    },
    {
      "product_id": 3,
      "product_name": "Blue Braclet",
      "price": 5,
      "quantity": 1,
      "image": "imageurl"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Refer this - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/

Comment: Is that cart collection ? So all you need is to check whether a product is already existing in `products` array or not, You don't need the user document/cart right ?

Comment: it is a document in side a collection  and thank you @bigbounty  thanks for the document link  I used find with $elemMatch and it worked

Answer (score 1):

you can query:

```
db.getCollection('collection_name').find({'products.product_id':{ $exists: true }})
```

This query will return the records which has `product_id` field.

Answer (score 0):

According to the use case you described - you do have the customer_id in addition to the product_id when you want to make the update.

So, to find out if the product exists in the customer's shopping cart you can incorporate both the customer id and the product_id in your query.

```
db.getCollection(<collection_name>).findOne({'customer_id': <customer_id>, 'products.product_id':<product_id>})
```

If this product id exists in the customer's cart, then the query would return it.